# ideavim in intellij is there a shortcut to goto next error?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm now in a file, I want to hit and it will go to next compilation error in my file i fix it, then hit again the shortcut will go to next error and so forth... i'm already in my text file i cant find how to navigate to next error while editing my text file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am just starting using intellij (changed from Eclipse) recently. For your question:

Right click the scroll bar, in the popup menu, choose the one (radio button) you need.

then in editor, press `F2` to jump to next error/problem. `shift-F2` back.

btw, this is not a `ideavim` shortcut.

Answer (score 13):

You can set shortcuts for intellij actions in ideavim. Below lines set `gn` and `gp` for next and previous errors.

```
% cat ~/.ideavimrc
nnoremap gn :action GotoNextError<CR>
nnoremap gp :action GotoPreviousError<CR>
```

More details: [Useful customizations in .ideavimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28059459)

Actionlist: https://gist.github.com/zchee/9c78f91cc5ad771c1f5d

Docs: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions

Comment: FYI: `gn` is an existing vim command for [operating on search matches](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)