# Useful customizations in .ideavimrc

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, rubymine, ideavim

I'm interested in hearing how some of you have customized your .ideavimrc file to improve your workflows within your Jetbrains IDE. I'm unsure of its capabilities and would love to know what can be customized. A list of possible customizations would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I have only one line in .ideavim file: `source ~/.vimrc`, but many features won't work in Intellij  :( ideavim is good, but compare to vim, it is afterall a compromise, we cannot expect that it arms Jetbrains IDE with full vim power.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically you can safely source your ~/.vimrc, but be aware that some tricky `:map` commands may break IntelliJ shortcuts (that was the reason why IdeaVim switched to its own configuration file instead of ~/.vimrc). The only non-Vim command supported by now (v 0.39) is [:action](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions). You can define multi-key bindings for IntelliJ actions instead of crazy shortcuts for 3 or more fingers. For example:

```
nnoremap ,c :action GotoClass<CR>
```

Comment: Can you tell me whole list of IDE actions? I need to map some of them.

Comment: @Vikrant See `:actionlist`.

Comment: to search for a specific action use `:actionlist <search-term>`

Answer (score 16):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/saaguero/ideavimrc/blob/master/.ideavimrc) or [this](https://github.com/vbauerster/dotfiles/blob/master/ideavimrc) configuration.
Also, bear in mind, that you can record a macro (Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording), and reference it later in your .ideavimrc file like so:
`nmap csw' :action Macro.surround_with_single_quote<CR>`

To find out action commands, use `:actionlist`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some useful materials that helped me write my `.ideavimrc`:

[`set` commands](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md) that work in IdeaVim.

[Jetbrains specific actions](https://gist.github.com/zchee/9c78f91cc5ad771c1f5d) (You can also see this list with `:actionlist`)

You map these actions in `.ideavimrc` like:

`nnoremap gd :action GotoDeclaration<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

Running :actionlist gives the list of possible actions

```
$Copy                                              <M-C>
$Cut                                               <M-X> <S-Del>
$Delete                                            <Del> <BS> <M-BS>
Actions.ActionsPlugin.GenerateToString
ActivateAntToolWindow
ActivateCommitToolWindow                           <M-0>
ActivateDatabaseChangesToolWindow
ActivateDatabaseToolWindow
...
...
```